# Prevent overflowing title in Bootstrap 4 navbar

Tags: overflow, navbar, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap 4 responsive application which displays the title of the currently select page for mobile users beside the navigation menu toggle button. If the title is too long, I would like it to be automatically shortened with ellipses. However, I can't get that to work. The title is not shortened and the navbar line is wrapped so that the title is under the menu toggle button instead of beside it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Nav with title and context menu</title>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-primary justify-content-start">
    <div class="container">
        <button id="navbar-toggler" class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
                data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="navbar-nav d-md-none" style="white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis">
            <span class="navbar-brand">
                Page title which should be beside the toggle button and shortened by ellipsis on mobile
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
            <div class="navbar-nav">
                <a href="#" class='nav-link'>Messages</a>
                <a href="#" class='nav-link'>About</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </nav>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col col-lg-10 offset-lg-1"
        ">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tristique, dui vitae pharetra
            sollicitudin, felis metus dignissim sapien, at sodales libero massa condimentum dui. </p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I achieve an automatic shortening of the title and non-wrapping of the menu bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add the `text-truncate` class AND also this `style="max-width: 210px;"` to the span.

216px seems to be the maximum you can do for 320px wide screens. So, I chose 210px to give it a bit of a breathing room on the smallest screens.

Here's the code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-primary justify-content-start">
    <div class="container">
        <button id="navbar-toggler" class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="navbar-nav d-md-none">
            <span class="navbar-brand text-truncate" style="max-width: 210px;">Page title which should be beside the toggle button and shortened by ellipsis on mobile</span>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
            <div class="navbar-nav">
                <a href="#" class='nav-link'>Messages</a>
                <a href="#" class='nav-link'>About</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col col-lg-10 offset-lg-1">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis ut tempore, ullam debitis, nihil commodi eligendi non porro nobis sapiente, iste, totam ex doloremque. Laboriosam dolore assumenda voluptatum minus commodi quidem voluptates optio!
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 4.5

I think the the best solution here is to wrap the `.navbar-brand` and `.navbar-toggler` in an additional flexbox that has the `.flex-nowrap` and `.w-100` styles applied to it.  Then, in the `.navbar-brand`, apply the `.text-truncate` style which will stop the text from causing the `button` to wrap to the next line

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <!-- begin flexbox containing brand and toggler -->
  <div class="d-flex flex-nowrap w-100">
    <a class="text-truncate navbar-brand" href="#">Very long navbar brand text that will ultimately need to be clipped with ellipsis on smaller screens than a 4K TV</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  </div>
  <!-- end flexbox containing brand and toggler -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- JS, Popper.js, and jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```